# $unwind multiple arrays present in the embedded documents and show each array as single document as output in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Refer below code. In this, field scenario is a embedded document which has has arrays and I want to showcase each array as a single document in the output. Note that each array contains embedded document in it so it would be helpful to get the code which extracts fields from those too. I'm not using java to query. Would be using external BI application which would be integrated in. Think I should also mention that i'm using NoSQLBooster for MongoDB application to create these queries.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": ""
    },
    "organisationId": "",
    "bcpId": "",
    "bcpName": "",
    "bcpDescription": "",
    "biaEntity": {},
    "version": "0.01",
    "status": "PENDING",
    "primaryBridgeNumber": "1",
    "alternateBridgeNumber": "2",
    "scenario": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5e3ab709367d2c5f5826c6fd"
        },
        "scenario": "",
        "strategies": [{
            "mdmStrategy": {},
            "strategy": {
                "pSIStrategyDetails": {
                    "scenarioName": "",
                    "strategyName": "",
                    "rto": "",
                    "sustainablePeriod": {

                    },
                    "description": "1",
                    "primaryContact": {
                    },
                    "secondaryContact": {
                    },
                    "recoverySite": {

                    }
                },
                "pSICriticalStaff": {},
                "specialRequirement": [{

                }, {

                }, {

                }, {

                }, {

                }]
            },
            "createdOn": {},
            "updatedOn": {}
        }, {
            "mdmStrategy": {},
            "strategy": {
                "pSIStrategyDetails": {},
                "pSICriticalStaff": {},
                "specialRequirement": [{
                },
                 {
                },
                 {
                },
                 {                  
                }, 
                {

                }]
            },
            "createdOn": {},
            "updatedOn": }
        }],
        "description": "",
        "status": "Active",
        "createdOn": {},
        "updatedOn": {}
    }],
    "updatedOn": {},
    "createdOn": {},
    "business_owner_id": {},
    "bc_coordinator_id": {},
    "backup_business_owner_id": {},
    "backup_business_coordinator_id": {},
    "sme_id": {},
    "_class": "com.bcm.bcp.api.model.BcmBcpEntity"
}
```

**expected output:**

```
{{
"bcpId": "",
"bcpName": "",
"bcpDescription": "",
"version": "0.01",
"status": "PENDING",
"scenario.scenario":"---",
"scenario.strategies.strategy.strategyName":"---",
"scenario.strategies.strategy.rto":"---",
etc...
}{
"bcpId": "",
"bcpName": "",
"bcpDescription": "",
"version": "0.01",
"status": "PENDING",
"scenario.scenario":"---",
"scenario.strategies.strategy.strategyName":"---",
"scenario.strategies.strategy.rto":"---",
etc...
}{
"bcpId": "",
"bcpName": "",
"bcpDescription": "",
"version": "0.01",
"status": "PENDING",
"scenario.scenario":"---",
"scenario.strategies.strategy.strategyName":"---",
"scenario.strategies.strategy.rto":"---",
etc...
}}
```

"scenario.scenario":"---","scenario.strategies.strategy.strategyName":"---",
"scenario.strategies.strategy.rto":"---",

will be coming from the arrays so the output will be number of elements present in the array

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You should show your desired output for the query that you want, please.

Comment: What is your expected output? The given data is long and it will be complex for us to understand. Could you give a smaller data (something which is similar to your data) and it's expected output?

Comment: @igorkf provided the expected o/p.

Comment: @ngShravil.py believe me but I've only provided 20% of the data. The architecture being used is really complex hence the trouble when extracting the data.

Comment: @relativelyPrime I apologise if there was some miscommunication. As you can see in the sample document structure, the document has embedded documents and these embedded documents has fields which has the data in arrays. I want to create a query which will get the fields data which are actually present in arrays of the embedded fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U hope this is what you want:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$scenario"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$scenario.strategies"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      bcpId: 1,
      bcpName: 1,
      bcpDescription: 1,
      version: 1,
      status: 1,
      scenario: {
        scenario: 1,
        strategies: {
          strategy: {
            pSIStrategyDetails: {
              rto: 1,
              strategyName: 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "bcpDescription": "",
    "bcpId": "",
    "bcpName": "",
    "scenario": {
      "scenario": "",
      "strategies": {
        "strategy": {
          "pSIStrategyDetails": {
            "rto": "",
            "strategyName": ""
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "status": "PENDING",
    "version": "0.01"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "bcpDescription": "",
    "bcpId": "",
    "bcpName": "",
    "scenario": {
      "scenario": "",
      "strategies": {
        "strategy": {
          "pSIStrategyDetails": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "status": "PENDING",
    "version": "0.01"
  }
]
```

**Explanation:** You need to use 2 `$unwind` operators, as it is like arrays of arrays and a `$project` operator to display only those fields, which you need.

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SxmYU8VwG2I)

**P.S.** - The question is still unclear.

Comment: if i'm not stepping out of bounds and being disrespectful could you specify as to exactly what part of the questions is unclear.

Comment: `"scenario.scenario":"---","scenario.strategies.strategy.strategyName":"---", "scenario.strategies.strategy.rto":"---",

will be coming from the arrays so the output`...

Comment: the strings in the double quotes are the paths of the fields.

Comment: Did you check the output mentioned in the answer, is this what you need?

Comment: yes i did, performed some experiments on the query. thank you man